# C++ std::cin is stuck at 80 lines of input

Tags: c++

here is the code that I have

```
int main() 
{
  int total = 0;
  int count = 0;
  std::cin >> total;


  int arr[4] = {0,0,0,0}; 

  while(count < total) 
  { 

    std::cin>>arr[0]>>arr[1]>>arr[2]>>arr[3];

    count++;
    std::cout<<count<<std::endl;

  }

 return 0;

 }
```

so the first line of input tells how many lines I need to read after..and each line has 4 numbers separated by space. Whenever the number of lines exceed 80(e.g 100), then the while loop gets stuck. I have no idea what causes the problem and I have tried a couple things like cin.clear() but they just didnt work....

**Edit:** std::cin stops reading after 80 lines of input with format like 10 20 210 10

Xcode with LLVM didn't work...However g++ using terminal works.... http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UXAMgM4ldn2K2NgU
here is the code that works on my terminal with g++ but not my xcode...

Comment: Your description of the problem is extremely vague. What do you mean by "gets stuck"? How are you testing exactly?

Comment: And what does line 80 of the input look like? Does it contain something that is not an integer?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg they are all integers like 10 20 30 40

Comment: Couldn't reproduced. It successfully stop after reading 128 lines. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JBcm4eyDXv2bwMQz

Comment: Use a debugger to see the state of each variable in each loop iteration. 95% that after such action you'll get the answer yourself.

Comment: @MikeCat I tried my data set on the website and it worked too.....I am using xcode

Answer (score 1):

It's the output that's getting stuck. Unless the output of the `count` is being read by something and consumed, eventually the output buffer will get full and the `cout` line will block.

Comment: how to reset the output buffer?

Comment: Why would you want to reset it exactly?

Comment: Sorry...you said the buffer is full so I thought maybe resetting it would let it continue..did I misunderstand something?

Comment: If you want to throw away the data rather than outputting it, remove the output line.

Comment: even if I remove the output line, it wouldnt work in xcode but it works in g++ with terminal. it's weird....